# How to make method entity_uri work when $entity_type is taxonomy_vocabulary?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, entities, uri

I have a table with entities of type *content*, *taxonomy_vocabulary* and *terms*. For *content* and *terms*, I can show a link to each detail page by using the method [entity_uri](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/entity_uri/7.x).

But for entities with type *taxonomy_vocabulary* this does not work, [entity_uri](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/entity_uri/7.x) returns null.

What is the best way to get the url for a *taxonomy_vocabulary* entity?

Comment: Taxonomy doesn't come with a default page to view a vocabulary. So I guess that is why entity_uri has nothing to return in this case. I am happy to get the admin page for the vocabulary, but that is not what is pretended in most cases.
I think there should be a default detail page for each vocabulary, listing its terms. And then entity_uri should return that uri natively.

Answer (score 1):

I hope it is not the best answer, because it requires customized code. But anyway, it is a possible solution and I'll share it.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_info().
 */
function mymodule_entity_info_alter(&$info) {
  if (isset($info['taxonomy_vocabulary'])) {
    $info['taxonomy_vocabulary']['uri callback'] = 'my_module_entity_info_uri_callback';
  }
}

/**
 * Return path for taxonomy_vocabulary entities
 */
function my_module_entity_info_uri_callback($taxonomy) {
  return array(
    'path' => 'admin/structure/taxonomy/' . $taxonomy->machine_name,
  );
}
```